# my node is running in development mode so how to change it that

Tags: corda

Hi I got some warning from Corda documentation examples
ATTENTION: This node is running in the development model! this is not safe for production deployments.
what's the reason for this warning??

Answer (score 1):

Corda raises a warning because the `devMode` configuration flag has few importants consequences on how things such as how node keystore is found, how the DB schema is checked/created, the Java heap size etc. Such configurations can be acceptable for a development phase of a Corda project, but not suitable for Production, so Corda gives the warning.

From the [Corda Node documentation](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/corda-configuration-fields.html#devmode) :

> This flag sets the node to run in development mode. On startup, if the
> keystore /certificates/sslkeystore.jks does not exist, a
> developer keystore will be used if devMode is true. The node will exit
> if devMode is false and the keystore does not exist. devMode also
> turns on background checking of flow checkpoints to shake out any bugs
> in the checkpointing process. Also, if devMode is true, Hibernate will
> try to automatically create the schema required by Corda or update an
> existing schema in the SQL database; if devMode is false, Hibernate
> will simply validate the existing schema, failing on node start if the
> schema is either not present or not compatible. If no value is
> specified in the node configuration file, the node will attempt to
> detect if it’s running on a developer machine and set devMode=true in
> that case. This value can be overridden from the command line using
> the --dev-mode option.
>
> This flag affects the default value for Java heap size.

You can also check [this](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/corda-configuration-file.html) out.

Answer (score 0):

To change from DEV mode to PROD mode, modify `devMode = true` to `devMode = false` inside `node.conf` file of your node, then restart the node.

Make sure that you sign the contract CorDapps when you move to PROD mode; read about it [here](https://blog.b9lab.com/why-you-need-to-sign-your-cordapps-and-how-to-do-it-464101e5ec71).